# How to delete a Discord message via disnake if it has a reaction

Tags: python, discord, disnake

How can I use the [disnake](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/index.html) library to write code (Discord bot) that deletes a message when a user with a special role (e.g. admin) reacts to the message?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the bot to use the event [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) to listen for reactions.

Then check if `str(Reaction.emoji) == wrench` and if `Reaction.user.roles.contains(<ADMIN ROLE>)`.

The admin role can be found with [`get_role(<ROLE ID>)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_role#discord.Guild.get_role) and the role ID can be found by sending the message `\@role_name` (usually `\@Admin`)in the discord server.

---

If both of those conditions are met, you'll want to run [`await Reaction.message.delete()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_reaction#discord.Message.delete).

---

While I didn't post a working example, I hope this is helpful in giving you an idea of how such a task would be accomplished.

Comment: thanks, but could you write pls a code with @bot.event? (: